# Can signal in std_logic have other value than 0 and 1?

Tags: vhdl

I've been learning VHDL (mostly on my own) during my studies. I've heard that I should always cover all possible situations in *case* or *if* statements. My question is: is it technically possible for *std_logic* internal signal to have any other value than 0 or 1?

For example, is this possible:

```
signal or_gate : std_logic;

...
or_gate <= input1 or input2;
...
if(or_gate = '1') then
--led blinks fast
elsif(or_gate = '0') then
--led blinks slow
else
--led off
end if;
```

or there can only be led blinks or led off?

Comment: In VHDL language yes. When synthesised on a real board inside a digital design, then no. If you're looking at an FPGA design (for example) usually you would use `if or_gate = '1' then ... else -- or_gate not '1'` . The else case in your design would usually only be considered in the simulation case usually to catch uninitialised (U) or unknown (X) values.

Comment: Practically, apart from H,L (which read as 1,0) the other values are "several different kinds of mistake". These are vital for debugging, but useless for your stated purpose. You need a second bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for bit type we have just 0 and 1, but std_logic type except 0 and 1, support other values.

So the std_logic type can have the following values:

- '1' : Logic 1
- '0' : Logic 0
- 'Z' : High impedance
- 'W' : Weak signal, can’t tell if 0 or 1
- 'L' : Weak 0, pulldown
- 'H' : Weak 1, pullup
- '-' : Don’t care
- 'U' : Uninitialized
- 'X' : Unknown, multiple drivers